# How do I copy files with different names form one folder to another folder using powershell?

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I have a folder with many different csv files in it all with different names.  I'm trying to copy a group of 129 of them to a different folder.  Each of the 129 have a different name.  Is there a way to do this in powershell all at once?  Maybe using copy-item but I'd need to be able to do something like; copy-item oldfolder\somename.csv AND oldfolder\anothername.csv AND etc. -destination differentexistingfolder

Comment: You want to copy all `*.csv` files from the source directory, or 129 _specific_ csv files?

Comment: do the 129 files have anything in common? are you trying to copy _all_ files from a folder to another folder?

Comment: I want to copy only 129 .csv files out of many other .csv files.  Each file has a different name. So 129 specific csv files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a text file with the file names, like:

```
file1.csv
file2.csv
someother.csv
...
```

You can do:

```
# read file names from txt file
$filenames = Get-Content path\to\file\with\names.txt

# find the files and copy them
Get-ChildItem -Path path\to\oldfolder\ -Filter *.csv |Where-Object { $filenames -contains $_.Name } |Copy-Item -Destination path\to\destination\
```